# How to collaborate on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, collaboration, kingswaysoft

I am currently working An SSIS project in visual studio that requires multiple people to work on it. We currently use GIT to get the information around, but one of the components, specific KingswaySoft Salesforce component, throw authentication errors every time a different user opens it. The project will still run, It just that that every time a different user opens the package they have to reenter the credentials. Is there a way to fix this in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for choosing our software as your integration solution.

This seems to be a problem of the ProtectionLevel setting of your SSIS package. Is it set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey? You can try to set this to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and provide a password for your package to see if it helps.

If you have any further questions, please feel free to reach out to us through our official support channel. We're more than happy to help.

KingswaySoft Support